# "apple-mobile-web-app-title" on Android

Tags: android, web-applications, title, meta-tags

is there an equivalent to iOS 6 meta tag `apple-mobile-web-app-title` for android web-applications? Something that gives you the possibility to define a long title and a short title.

```
<title>Long name</title>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Short name">
```

Answer (score 6):

This is possible using the "application-name" meta tag. However it only appears to work with chrome. Firefox and the android browser don't use the title tag

```
<head> ...  <meta name="application-name" content="Awesome App!"> ...  </head>
```

From, Usage in web applications section
http://w3c-webmob.github.io/installable-webapps/

Comment: Then how can set default title for Firefox

Answer (score 2):

Create a JSON file called `site.webmanifest`, that looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "Long name",
  "short_name": "Short name",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/android-chrome-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/android-chrome-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "display": "standalone"
}
```

Then add it to your HTML like this:

```html
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
```

The `"icons"` part is irrelevant to your question, but you should probably include them as well (and actually make those icon files). I got this from this article: https://dev.to/masakudamatsu/favicon-nightmare-how-to-maintain-sanity-3al7

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has added support for JSON-based manifest file for your web app [since M39](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen). The field `short_name` is equivalent to Safari's `apple-mobile-web-app-title` in that it would be preferred where there is limited space to display the full name, e.g. app launcher.

[W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/#short_name-member) for `short_name` field in web app manifest file:

> The short_name member is a string that represents a short version of the name of the web application. It is intended to be used where there is insufficient space to display the full name of the web application.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by using javascript to detect the mobile browser and then change **document.title** to a shorter title:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod|Android|Silk)/gi))
   document.title = "Short Title";
```