# apple-mobile-web-app-title for Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html

The original question was falsely duplicated, and hasn't been opened for over a year, so I'm asking it again. Link: ["apple-mobile-web-app-title" on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083788/apple-mobile-web-app-title-on-android)

is there an equivalent to iOS's meta tag `apple-mobile-web-app-title` for android web-applications? Something that gives you the possibility to define an alternate title for Android's Add to Home Screen functionality.

```
<title>Long name</title>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Short name">
```

Comment: Please refer to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32367360/1536718) in the post [“apple-mobile-web-app-title” on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083788/apple-mobile-web-app-title-on-android/32367360#32367360)